# How to call a function with a different string starting points?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I have a function that takes a string. I want to call this function recursively with different starting points.

```
int findall(string str){
    if(str.length()<=2){
        return 0;
    }
    return findall(str+1)+findall(str+2);
}
```

How to recursively call with the string's 2nd and 3rd positions?

Comment: You could turn it into a C string, increment the pointer and make it a std::string again

Comment: sry,I should be careful with tags from next time

Comment: @RanElgiser Did You mean by converting the string into a char array?

Comment: What exactly is `findall` supposed to do? It doesn't seem to be finding anything?

Comment: Isn't this a really expensive way to make a function equivalent to `return 0`? Your only base case returns 0, so adding up the results of other calls can only give 0 also.

Comment: @Amartya Roy You are trying to get `0` as in your recursive function as it always returns 0 for a string less than size 2. What is your final aim with this function?

Comment: this function was meant to check the first character wheater it is >0  or not and the sum of 1st and 2nd character whether it is >0 and <=26, then recursively check for all other possible substring starting from str[1] and str[2].

Comment: What's the *exact* problem with the code you have?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is not possible with c++ `std::string`s; however, if you can convert the function so that it takes begin and end iterators as input then you can call it like this:

```
int findall(std::string::const_iterator begin, std::string::const_iterator end){
    if ((end - begin) <= 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return findall(begin + 1, end) + findall(begin + 2, end);
}
```

With this method you can also avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: Have you ever heard of `std::basic_string::substr`?

Comment: @bipll `substr` creates copies of the substrings, which this answer avoids.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Exactly so, so what? 'Avoids' is not exactly 'not possible'.

Answer (score 1):

`str+1` mens nothing.

The same semantics can be achieved with

```
int findall(string str)
{
    if(str.length()<=2)
    {  return 0;  }
    return findall(str.substr(1))+findall(str.substr(2));
}
```

Unluckily, that generates copy of strings every time a substring is needed.
Since you don't need to modify them, you can be more efficient  with

```
int findall(string_view str)
{
    if(str.length()<=2)
    {  return 0;  }
    return findall(str.substr(1))+findall(str.substr(2));
}
```

Unlike `string`, `string_view` does not own the data (it's just a pointer & size pair) and a `substr` of a `string_view` is just anotehr string_view on the same string data.

Whatever const char* or string can convert implicitly into a string_view, so you can call this function anyway.

It remains anyhow completely obscure to me what the purpose of that function should be and what the verb "find" would mean.

Comment: As you pointed out, string_view is ideal for exactly what the OP was asking for. But its worth noting that string_view is C++17 and the question is tagged C++11.

Comment: @definecindyconst: I saw wrong tags so many times that I'll let the OP to decide.